# Source command not unable to find file when run within a shell script

Tags: linux, macos

I have script which calls another script file using source command below is my script file

```
 echo "script starting"
 source common_util.sh
 -- other commands ---
```

at the line 2 I get this error.

```
No such file or directory/common_util.sh
```

I have even tried with `./` still it returns the same error,

But Actually file exists in that folder, `PWD` is same as parent script and `common_util.sh`

But if I run `common_util.sh` separately from command line,
`source common_util.sh`
its working, but when include this above not working.

I am running this on `MacOS seirra`

Please advise on this.

**Parent -script **

```
  echo  "starting script"
  root_folder=$(dirname $0)"/"
  echo "before starting scripts  $root_folder"
  #import common_util script
  source ./common_util1.sh
```

**common_util1.sh**

```
 echo "This is in common_util1.sh"
```

**output**

```
  users/> sh parent_script.sh 
  starting script
  before starting scripts  ./
  : No such file or directory/common_util1.sh
```

Comment: Are both the files in same directory?

Comment: @Santoshb yes.. they are in same directory

Comment: Please provide exact script, exact output and exact full run log.

Comment: @kaylum please check I have added as you have requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my script was written in windows OS, so when I tried to run that script in Mac OS, its has those hidden carriages `\r` which causing the shell to treat filename differently then resulting in no file found error.

So I have converted that script file and rest of the supporting script files to be compatible with Mac OS using `dos2unix` command, you can find below link to install `dos2unix`

[dos2unix home brew link](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/dos2unix)